# Will Spring 4.1 support JSF 2.2?

Tags: jsf-2.2, view-scope, spring-4

Some time ago I heard a rumor saying Spring 4.1 is going to support JSF 2.2. In particular, SpringBeanFacesELResolver would be able to create view scoped controller beans. Spring 3 only supports application scope, request scope and session scope. As far as I know Spring 4.0 supports the same scopes.

Unfortunately, I don't find the reference on Spring 4.1 and JSF 2.2 (except my own web site, where I mention I had heard the rumor). Are there any plans concerning Spring 4.1 and JSF 2.2?

BTW: I know there are several questions on StackOverflow dealing with Spring and JSF. My question is different in that it's specifically about Spring 4.1 and it's about native Spring support. In particular, it's not about how to implement ViewScope myself.

Answer (score 0):

Rafael Ponte told me today @ViewScope can be used with the latest Spring 3.2 version. See the full story (including Rafaels comments) at [my blog](http://www.beyondjava.net/blog/integrate-jsf-2-spring-3-nicely).

As for Spring 4.1: the plans to support JSF 2.2 have been dropped. The [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6543) on the topic has been moved to "contribution welcome" - in other words they're waiting for us to implement it ourselves and to submit our solution to the Spring team.